# How to record voice over existing voice tracks using Audacity

Tags: recording, audacity

I am trying to record singing using Audacity. Once I hit the record button is record my singing, but how to I overlay the existing recording if I wanted to keep parts of the tracks and re-record some parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start a new track.

You can insert silence over the parts you don't want to keep, or mute the sections, and record the new parts in a new track.

Audacity will also cut and paste across tracks, so you can build a final track with cut out pieces of the previous tracks you recorded. If you are recording to a backing track or click, you can mute each track after you record it to do another take on a new track.

it also has a cross fade function you can apply to the spliced pieces.