# How to make Audacity record in loop

Tags: software, homerecording, audacity

I know how to loop PLAY (with shift+space after defining a region), but i can't find how to **record while looping** the region.

Precisely: I want to record multiple versions of the same vocal line in a single session, without declaring a new track everytime.

Is it even possible? If not I might change software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called on track overdubbing and, I am afraid, [is not possible in Audacity](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_multi_track_overdubbing.html) (and probably most "linear" editors).

The main reason for this is that doing so would not add anything compared to create multiple tracks, and then mixing them. This way, you can apply effects and post-treatments to the each tracks before mixing while, with a real on track overdub that would not be possible. See also [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70171/how-to-record-voice-over-existing-voice-tracks-using-audacity?rq=1).